# How to know if a drive is subseted in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-xp, command-line

I did:

```
C:\> subst d:\ c:
C:\>wmic logicaldisk get description,deviceid,drivetype
Description       DeviceID    DriveType
Local Fixed Disk  C:          3
Local Fixed Disk  D:          3
```

How I know that drive D is virtual (`substed`)? Maybe there is another command?

(It should suppoet WindowsXP...10)

Comment: Does it have to be using wmic? Just issuing the `subst` command will tell you.

Comment: Simple and genius.